# "git-push" and "git push" are different?

Tags: git

```
> git --version 
git version 1.8.4.3 

> git-push https://carter.barry:password@code.google.com/p/bcapps/ 

error: Cannot access URL https://carter.barry:password@code.google.com/p/bcapps\
/, return code 22 
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://carter.barry:password@code.google.c\
om/p/bcapps/' 

> git push https://carter.barry:password@code.google.com/p/bcapps/  
Everything up-to-date
```

I always thought "git push" was the same thing as "git-push".

Why does one work and not the other (I've also tried it when the 
working directory had changes, similar results).

EDIT: Thanks, @mohamed-stark, you are correct!

It turns out git-push was leftover from an earlier version of git, was located in /usr/libexec/git-core/git-push, and had a much older timestamp (from 2009). Older versions of git are known to not handle https pushing/pulling well.

When I installed the newer version of git, it apparently did not wipe-out this older version (not that it necessarily should).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing called git-push

All commands for git have a space after the git command

As git is the command and the options is push - pull - .....

so using git-push is consider (git-push) as a command and there is no command have that name.

Comment: There is a `git-push`.  It usually lives at `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-push` if it's a system install, or `/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-push` if you build and install it yourself.  It has not ceased to exist, it's just no longer generally on your path since it lives in `libexec/git-care`.  The `git` command often looks for an executable to delegate to and use `exec()` to execute it.  It'll look on the PATH but it also looks in `libexec/git-core`.  This same mechanism allow you to create your own git commands by naming the script `git-NAME` and putting it on your path.